# Deploying Symfony2 app with capifony fails at cache warmup

Tags: symfony, capistrano, capifony

I have been battling with this for hours now, but now I am stuck with this and I can't move on.

When Capifony gets to the cache warmup stage, it fails when trying to load a vendor class, but it appears that the path to the vendor dir is wrong;

```
** [out :: example.com] PHP Fatal error:  main(): Failed opening required '/var/www/example.com/releases/20120917131025/src/MyBundle/Bundle/ProcessBundle/Controller../../../../../../vendor/quail/quail/quail.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/example.com/releases/20120917131025/src/MyBundle/Bundle/ProcessBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php on line 0
```

You can see that it hasn't built the directory correctly;

```
ProcessBundle/Controller../../
```

should be

```
ProcessBundle/Controller/../../
```

The particular vendor dir/class it cannot load is actually in the repo, its the only one not being loaded through bin/vendors because its not available in a public git repo.

My deploy.rb is pretty uneventful, it hasn't always looked like this, but commenting things out and changing values constantly over the last few hours has taken its toll..

```
set :application, "project"
set :domain,      "example.com"
set :deploy_to,   "/var/www/example.com/"
set :app_path,    "app"
set :repository,  "git@github.com:project/project.git"
set :scm,         :git
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :model_manager, "doctrine"
# Or: `propel`
role :web,        domain                         # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app,        domain                         # This may be the same as your `Web`     server
role :db,         domain, :primary => true       # This is where Symfony2 migrations will     run
set  :keep_releases,  3
set :user, "deployer-user"
set :runner, "deployer-user"
set :webserver_user,    "deployer-user"
set :branch, "master"
set :port, 2222
# Be more verbose by uncommenting the following line
logger.level = Logger::MAX_LEVEL
default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
set   :use_sudo,      false
set :shared_files,      ["app/config/parameters.ini"]
set :shared_children,     [app_path + "/logs", web_path + "/uploads", "vendor"]
# set :update_vendors,    true
# set :use_composer, true
```

Thanks in advance.

*EDIT* I had a path in a require that was killing it. Updated and now its working fine. Closing question.